# Import alias for a typescript package is referencing the build folder, but I want it to just be the module name

Tags: typescript, npm, lerna, npm-publish

I have a typescript package in a lerna monorepo project and it will be published to npm. Right now the other consuming packages in my own app are only working when I reference it like

```js
import { Component } from '@company/api/lib`;
```

However, I want it to look like this

```js
import { Component } from '@company/api`;
```

I'm not sure what I have configured incorrectly in my project.

The directory structure is like this

```
api
|-lib <--this is the build output>
|-src <--original source files>
|--index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

**package.json configuration**

```json
{
  "name": "@company/api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Public API platform.",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "lib/api.js",
  "typings": "lib/api.d.ts",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "__tests__"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "removeComments": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: using barrel index should fix this problem, see [How to add Barrels in TypeScript (or JavaScript)](https://dev.to/luispa/how-to-create-barrels-in-typescript-or-javascript-59ma)

Comment: @ghiscoding I do have a barrel index file.